# FatalExecutionEngineError detected in C# code after calling TerminateThread in C++ code

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, access-violation

If I call TerminateThread from C++ code, then later I'm getting FatalExecutionEngineError MDA later. That error mostly occurs when I'm doing different operations on strings (i.e. concat). Code listed below is just shows how to reproduce it.

Why it happens? How can I fix it and still use TerminateThread?

Thanks

Error is:

```
FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. 
The address of the error was at 0x7880bb35, on thread 0x18f0. 
The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. 
Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

C++ code:
Module.cpp:

```
#include "ThreadModule.h"
using namespace ThreadModule;

DWORD WINAPI workThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    while(1) {
        System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(5);
        printf(".");
    }
    return 0;
}

bool Module::StartThread() {
    handle = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        workThread,
        NULL,
        0,
        &threadIdInput);
    return true;    
}

bool Module::StopThread() {
    TerminateThread(handle, 0);
    handle = NULL;
    return true;
}
```

C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Module module = new Module();

    module.StartThread();
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        s += i.ToString();
    }
    module.StopThread();
    s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        s += i.ToString();  //After ~250 iteration get exception
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Completed!!");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of horrible thing that calling TerminateThread can cause... You should use some form of synchronous solution to terminate your threads.

Comment: "TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. **You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination.**" [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717\(v=vs.85\).aspx). You're violating the emphasized part by using the CLR. Follow the advice of @MatthewWatson and terminte your threads in a controlled manner.

Comment: There is exactly one possible answer to this question: Don't use TerminateThread. I cannot see any way how it would do what you want (even if you think it does). Basically, it is impossible to control all code that a thread executes. So you cannot use it, ever.

Comment: If you decide to continue using TerminateThread, but remove all CLR code from your native class, you need to additionally use a #pragma managed(off). In my own code that uses TerminateThread (unavoidable, by the way, in my case) I was hitting memory corruption until I added the pragma. This was necessary even though my native class had zero CLR code in it.

Answer (score 4):

```
   System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(5);
```

The thread you started is running managed code, not native C++ code.  Clearly you compiled this with the /clr option in effect so you could write C++/CLI code.  That's a problem, the CLR knows about that thread.  Necessarily so, it needs to look at the thread's stack when running the garbage collector to look for managed object references.

That makes killing the thread with TerminateThread() is problem, more than it already is, it is a dangerous winapi function that performs no cleanup.  The CLR falls over when it scans the stack of that dead thread.

The CLR can perform safe thread aborts with Thread::Abort().  That still doesn't make it a good idea to do so, but at least you are not going to make your program keel over this badly.  Note that Abort() will not work when the thread is running native code.  It is certainly best to completely write off the idea that aborting threads is a good idea.

An obvious place to ask the thread nicely to stop is the while(1) statement.